# Python line.split(':') len is 2 but still Value Error

Tags: python, email, split

I have run into a problem that I just have not been able to solve. Quite simply, I have 2 text files, one is the hashes_found which is in the format of

```
uncrackedHash:crackedHash
```

and the second file, email_list is in the format of:

```
email:uncrackedHash
```

Now what I am trying to do, is to print out the email and cracked hash, if the uncracked hash is the same.

The error I keep getting is:

```
email, uncracked = i.split(':')
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

yet the len(i) = 2

Also, I know that my opening files is unconventional and bad practice, it shouldn't affect the code though. That is just how I learned Python 2 years ago, and I will get into that convention as soon as I learn the proper way.

```
hashes_found = open('hashes_found.txt', 'r')
email_list = open('email_list.txt', 'r')

for i in email_list:
    i = i.strip()
    email, uncracked = i.split(':')

    for j in hashes_found:
        j = j.strip()

        try:
            uncracked_2, cracked = j.split(':')
        except Exception,e:
            print e
            continue

        if uncracked == uncracked_2:
            print email, ':', cracked
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: could it be that you have empty lines in the file?

Comment: Unrelated but critical bug: if you loop over a file object repeatedly, all iterations after the first will see it as empty. Thus, the inner `for` loop will fail almost every time.

Comment: len(i.split(':')) = 2 Thanks for the answers, how do you bypass the empty lines then? Isn't that what the try/except is for?

Comment: Put the failing statement inside a `try/except` and print `i`'s value in `except` branch

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't this be `for i in email_list.readlines():` rather than `for i in email_list:`?

Comment: You could also have more than one `:` in a line. Then you will have the same error.

Comment: hmm there must be something wrong with one of the lines I have. How would I skip a bad line? I thought the try/except then continue would be sufficient

Comment: You've done try/except in another place

Answer (score 1):

You say that `len(i)` is 2, but that is not the same as `len(i.split(':'))`...

My guess: you have empty lines, and use the DOS format (so the line is `\r\n`).

To skip empty lines:

```
for i in email_list:
    i = i.strip()

    if i == '':
        continue
```

It's also possible that the line doesn't have a `:`, you can skip those with something like:

```
for i in email_list:
    i = i.strip()

    if i == '':
        continue

    try:
        email, uncracked = i.split(':')
    except ValueError:
        print("Warning: this line has no `:'\n  %s" % i, file=sys.stderr)
        # Or python2:
        # print >> sys.stderr, "Warning: this line has no `:'\n  %s" % i
        continue
```

Comment: hashes_found is in the format of

uncrackedHash:crackedHash

and the second file, email_list is in the format of:

email:uncrackedHash

Comment: I don't trust such affirmations. Print the value when it fails

Comment: ladida@hahaha.ru 25097c51e8b82bdef8af9983f8daaf76 too many values to unpack   is the result from print email, uncracked, e in except

Comment: You should `print i`, otherwise you are printing the previous values of `email` and `untracked`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a aux variable:

```
    hashes_found = open('hashes_found.txt', 'r')
    email_list = open('email_list.txt', 'r')

    for i in email_list:
        aux = i.strip('\r\n').split(':')

        email= aux[0]
        uncracked = aux[1]
```

Comment: I will look into this, but I feel I shouldn't need this to get my code working. Thanks for the answer

Comment: This will still raise an error if `aux` has a length of 1... this just moves the problem, and doesn't solve anything.